# After Importing Excel Sheet In SAS DATA SET whether we can insert a column using SAS programming

Tags: sas

After Importing Excel Sheet In SAS DATA SET whether we can insert a column using SAS programming. If yes, please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a column is done simply by assignment, ie,

```
newvar = oldvar*2;
```

or whatever you want to do to create the new variable.  SAS does not have variable declarations, although you may want to define the format or length of the variable beforehand depending on your circumstances (it will be automatically assigned a format and length based on how you created it, but that automatic length may not be what you want).

You need to do that in a data step, or some other step that creates a new table.  You can do that without naming it differently, but that simply creates a new table that replaces a table; you cannot add a new column without rewriting the entire table in the data step language

IE:

```
data want;
set want;
newvar=oldvar*2;
run;
```

That will rewrite the entire `want` dataset with a new column.

You can also do it using `PROC SQL`, if you're more comfortable with that; you can either use `ALTER TABLE` or you can create a new table (or perhaps a replacement table) similar to other SQL implementations.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done by assigning the value to a new variable, like `NewAirCost` in the example below.  With the `var` statement you can select the newly created variable/column to be displayed.  It will depened on how the values are going to be populated.

SAS Example:

> VAR statement in the PROC PRINT step determines which variables are displayed in the output

```
data newair;
   set mylib.internationaltours;
   NewAirCost = AirCost + 10;

proc print data=newair;
   var Country AirCost NewAirCost;
   title 'Increasing the Air Fare by $10 for All Tours';
run;
```

Check [Adding Information to a SAS Data Set](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001315210.htm)

Comment: The `VAR` statement - indeed, the entire code from `proc print` on down - is irrelevant to the variable assignment; it is simply showing that the assignment worked.

Comment: @Joe, true. It is copied from support.sas.com for the purpose you mentioned. DownVoter: Why the -1 if I may ask?

Comment: The explanation in your answer is simply incorrect, as I noted above.  "It can be done with the `var` statement" is not correct; the `var` statement is a part of `proc print`, not a part of the data step, and is simply specifying what to print to the screen to show that the example worked.  Adding a column was done by the assignment operator (`=`) and nothing further.